# How can i store the value in different float type variable from received sms in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I am making a simple application which get value through SMS. Now i want to use this value in main activity to make calculation. My received SMS is something like this "12.64701.234" where 12.64 ,70 and 1.234 are different values how can separate them. like
a = 1264;b=70;c=1.234;

My code in main activitiy is

```
     private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //---display the SMS received in the TextView---
        TextView SMSes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay); 
        SMSes.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("sms"));
     }
     };
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.check);        

    //---intent to filter for SMS messages received---
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
    //---register the receiver---
    registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter); 
    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.statuscheck);        
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {                
            sendSMS("***********", "check");
            /*
            Intent i = new 
                Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.putExtra("address", "5556; 5558; 5560");
            i.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello my friends!");
            i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            startActivity(i);
            */                            
        }
      });
       }
       @Override
       protected void onResume() {
      //---register the receiver---
      //registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
      super.onResume();
       }
      @Override
     protected void onPause() {
    //---unregister the receiver---
    //unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
      super.onPause();
      } 
      //protected void onDestroy(){
     //unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
     //  super.onPause();  
    /  /}
      /*
     //---sends an SMS message to another device---
       private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
     {     
      SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
      sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
     }
      */   
     //---sends an SMS message to another device---
     private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
     {        
     String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
     String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

     PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);
     PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
     //---when the SMS has been sent---
     registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
         @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
          }
         }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

       //---when the SMS has been delivered---
          registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                        
            }
        }
      }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        
       SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
      sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
      }   
     }
```

Comment: if you separate them with space in SMS the you can do like this  :

String stringArray[] = smsBody.split(" ");

smsBody should be string. and then after parse array element in float.

Answer (score 0):

While send sms pass number with some pre identification and in some format so while read you can replace pre identification and format to differentiate the pattern.